# How to write fall back logic in ext js?

Tags: javascript, extjs

In Java script we write

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
    window.jQuery || document.write('<script 
      src="/Scripts/Plugins/JQuery/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')
</script>
```

Can any one explain how to write for ext.js?

Comment: Yes. Replace the references to the jQuery files with references to Ext JS files and check for the Ext global object instead of the jQuery global object.

Answer (score 0):

Why use a CDN if you use ExtJs? Off course it is possible to do so, but you want to build your own app.js which contains everything (and only) what you need. Besides that you don't want to edit your index.html after building your apps with Sencha Cmd.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//url/to/the/extjs/framework/ext.js"></script>
<script>
    window.Ext || document.write('<script 
      src="/path/to/your/framework/ext.js"><\/script>')
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Tarabass! I am still getting error. I have tried with this.<script type="text/javascript" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/Peddle/StaticResources/ext-3.4.1/ext-all.js"></script>  
 <script>window.Ext|| document.write('<script src="/js/ext-3.4.1/ext-all.js"><\/script>')</script>   Getting error like :Uncaught ReferenceError: Ext is not defined

Comment: If you type in the console of your browser `window.Ext`, is it also undefined?

Comment: Yes, In console I am getting undefined.

Comment: I assume the path to the framework is incorrect. If one of the paths is correct `window.Ext` should not be undefined anymore.